# Left- or Center-Justifying Multiline Section Header for List in SwiftUI

Tags: list, swiftui, header, alignment, sections

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header:
                VStack {
                    Text("Header line 1")
                    Text("This is header line 2")
            }) {
                List {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 2")
                    Text("Item 3")
                    Text("Item 4")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that I can't get both lines of the section header to justify or align in the same way. I'd prefer them both to be left-justified, but I would settle for them both to be centered to the screen as well. As it is, the alignment is strange, as shown below:

[image: Odd Text Alignment]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add VStack alignment

```
Section(header:
    VStack(alignment: .leading) { //<< here alignment
        Text("Header line 1")
        Text("This is header line 2")
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for how to have it centered, this worked for me. To remove auto-capitalization add .textCase(nil)

```
Section(header:
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        VStack {
            Text("Header line 1")
            Text("This is header line 2")
        }
        Spacer()
    }) {

}
.textCase(nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `headerProminence` modifier

```
Section("Section Title") {
   Text("Content")
}
.headerProminence(.increased)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Section(
    header: Text(section)
              .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
)
```

[image]